# Can't format a usb volume using fdisk

Tags: format, usb, mount, fat32

I tried to format a usb flash disk to FAT32 using `fdisk /dev/sdb`(I created a new partition and saved changes with `w`) and `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb` but when i eject and mount the volume again,it looks like it's empty.

```
dmesg | tail
```

outputs:

```
[ 8583.830684] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8583.830801] scsi host5: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 8584.864614] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 8584.865005] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 8584.865070] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 31283200 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[ 8584.865194] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 8584.865196] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[ 8584.865314] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 8584.865318] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 8584.870170] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 0):

> `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb`

Running this command overwrites any partitioning of the disk. You should have used

`mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1`

instead. This will create the filesystem on the first partition of `sdb`.